# Can I parallelize a function which by default returns a list? (in R)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Can I parallelize a function which by default returns a list? (in R) I have tried with the parLapply function of the parallel package, but I did not succeed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `parLapply` can return a list of lists. If the function called by `parLapply` returns a list that's what you get.

```r
library(parallel)

# data 
data(mtcars)

# function - model fit on bootstrapped samples from the Boston dataset
model_fit <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(mtcars)
  i <- sample(n, n, replace = TRUE)
  fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars[i, ])
  fit
}

# detect the number of cores
n.cores <- detectCores() - 2L
# Repl bootstrap replicates
Repl <- 100L

cl <- makeCluster(n.cores)
clusterExport(cl, "mtcars")
model_list <- parLapply(cl, 1:Repl, model_fit)
stopCluster(cl)

# a list of class "lm"
summary(model_list[[1]])
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars[i, ])
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -2.86272 -0.80106 -0.08815  0.68233  2.79325 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) -19.353679  20.403857  -0.949 0.353648    
#> cyl          -9.469350   1.921317  -4.929 7.10e-05 ***
#> disp          0.008405   0.014370   0.585 0.564876    
#> hp            0.037101   0.020395   1.819 0.083185 .  
#> drat          9.573765   2.289820   4.181 0.000421 ***
#> wt           -2.543876   2.111203  -1.205 0.241630    
#> qsec          3.360474   1.091440   3.079 0.005692 ** 
#> vs          -32.223824   6.698522  -4.811 9.39e-05 ***
#> am          -26.326478   5.534103  -4.757 0.000107 ***
#> gear         11.903213   2.420963   4.917 7.30e-05 ***
#> carb         -4.022473   1.047176  -3.841 0.000949 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.745 on 21 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9437, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9169 
#> F-statistic:  35.2 on 10 and 21 DF,  p-value: 7.204e-11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>